# Includes not displaying on Wordpress (PHP 7.2)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site in a root folder with a Wordpress blog in a "blog" folder". I'm trying to `include` the `header` and `footer` and loading only the "middle content" (blog index, blog single...) but I can't get it to work. I'm using Wordpress 7.2.

The `include` is just after the `<body>` tag in the `Header.php` of my theme parent (I have an child theme active too):

```
<body id="page-top"> 
<?php include('https://residenciarucab.es/generic-php/header.php'); ?>     
<div id="blog-container">
```

You can see live example here: https://residenciarucab.es/blog/

If u navigate to other sections like https://residenciarucab.es/rucab or https://residenciarucab.es/, you will see that the includes header.php and footer.php loads good, only happens to me on https://residenciarucab.es/blog/

I don't have any errors in the log browser console, so I don't know what am I failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` call should not use the public web URL of the file, you need to include the local file using a relative path.

You should do something similar to the following:

```php
<body id="page-top"> 
<?php require ABSPATH . '/../generic-php/header.php'; ?>  
<div id="blog-container">
```

`ABSPATH` refers to the wordpress root (so `httpdocs/blog`)
so we should look inside the parent folder of blog for a generic-php folder

Comment: I tried with: <?php require __DIR__ . '../generic-php/header.php'; ?>     and <?php require __DIR__ . './generic-php/header.php'; ?>     but gives me a blank page.

Comment: Can you check your web host error logs, it should tell you why it's not working. Most likely it's an incorrect path.

Comment: The path should be set in relation to where the `Header.php` file is in your theme. Is it in the same directory, or the parent directory?

Comment: Is in the parent directory of "blog".

Comment: try `<?php require __DIR__ . '/../generic-php/header.php'; ?>`

Comment: Blank again. I paste the error log:  PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/vhosts/residenciarucab.es/httpdocs/blog/wp-content/themes/garfunkel/../generic-php/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/residenciarucab.es/httpdocs/blog/wp-content/themes/garfunkel/header.php on line 41\n

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196731/discussion-between-pedro-corchero-murga-and-atymic).